# Web part SecurityException -- System.Net.WebPermission failed -- Farm Solution

Tags: 2010, web-part, security, farm-solution

I am getting an error with trying to make a HttpWebRequest inside a web part, I'm getting a SecurityException saying that System.Net.WebPermission failed. While searching for an answer, I came across [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26294/sandbox-webpart-web-requests-system-security-securityexception). One of the answers was to use a farm solution. I'm very new to developing with SharePoint so I'm not exactly sure what this means.

I currently have a development SharePoint VM set up with Visual Studio running on it. How would I be able to work on my web part and be able to not get this exception thrown?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a SharePoint project in VS, look at the dialog that appears: it asks which site you want to use for debugging, and the second question is whether you want it to be a sandbox or a farm solution. (or, for an existing project, you can change this in the properties of the project).

There's already been a lot written on both, so read up on them and post any specific questions you have.